# Need weekly mysql zabbix report for CPU,memory,disk space

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Please help us in to generate weekly report.

We used zabbix provided database.

Server Details

OS-Redhat 6.4
Mysql Server version: 5.5.17

We used below query for current time.

**Query:**

```
select h.host "Device Type",
replace(replace(replace(i.name,'$1',substring_index(substring_index(i.key_,',',1),'[',-1)),
'$2',substring_index(substring_index(i.key_,',',2),',',-1)),
'$3',substring_index(substring_index(i.key_,',',-1),']',1)) "Parameter Description",
i.lastvalue/1024/1024/1024 "VALUE",
i.delay "Polling Interval(in min)" from hosts h, items i, interface n 
where h.hostid=n.hostid and h.hostid=i.hostid and h.status=0 and i.status=0 and h.host='CRMAPP01' order by h.host;)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What's the problem with that query? Please add more details.

Comment: no problem in query but its show curret report...but i need weekly report...

Comment: This is hard to answer once we don't know the tables names of zabbix. I think a better way to do this is using the zabbix api. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment zabbix has no built-in auto-reporting function, the best way for this is to use an external programm like Pentaho Reporting to run this every month (automaticly)